# How to set the proxy used by DOMDocument60.ValidateNode?

Tags: xml, vba, xsd

I Use the following code to validate a xml-file in VBA:

```
    Dim dParseError As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError
With New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Call .Load("C:\Temp\mySample.xml")
    Set dParseError = .validateNode(.ChildNodes.item(1))
    If dParseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        Call msg_error_norm(ModuleName, FunctionName, "Error " & dParseError.ErrorCode & ": '" & dParseError.Reason & "' in XML-Vaidate.")
    End If
End With
```

But it seems like validate is not able to validate the schema correctly  which is in a a xsi:schemaLocation="http://..." location. This does not work because of our proxy configuration (At least this is what I suspect).

So how to set the proxy (read automatic configuration if possible) used by .validateNode?

Comment: Did you previously declared `dParseError As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError`?

Comment: yes I did => changed the question

Comment: I would also try `dParseError As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError2`. I must confess I do not know what difference exists between the two objects and I do not have such a file to make tests...

Comment: I tried MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError2 too but there is no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed like there is no need to set the proxy. Instead you have to load the Schema seperatly into a XMLSchemaCache and set this in the DOMDocument.

```
Dim dParseError As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError
Dim dSchemaCache As MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60 
With New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set dSchemaCache = New MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60
    Call dSchemaCache.Add("http://myNamespace/Schema", "http://www.locationOfTheSchema.at/GBS/Sample.xsd")
    Call .Load("C:\Temp\mySample.xml")
    Set dParseError = .validateNode(.ChildNodes.item(1))
    If dParseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        Call msg_error_norm(ModuleName, FunctionName, "Error " & dParseError.ErrorCode & ": '" & dParseError.Reason & "' in XML-Vaidate.")
    End If
End With
```